# Mega.co.nz image thumbnail, preview, cache?

Tags: caching, thumbnails

If I open for the first time some image on mega.co.nz, it takes some time to full load. If I open the same image for example next day on mega.co.nz, the image is loads immediately. Where is the image stored in my PC? How is it possible that the image loads quickly?

Answer (score 0):

The pc stores the images in cache this is a folder within your browser app. Cache is for speeding up page load times when you revisit a website as the data is already in cache so no need to download it again.